# Reply From User Not On Message

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an app that will display mail conversations and allow users to reply. In some cases a user (userB) who was not previously included in the conversation wants to join in. I would like for this newcomer to be able to reply or somehow add to the conversation (with them as the `from` address).

I've tried this:

```
client.post('/users/userA@example.com/messages/<message ID>/reply', {
  message:{
    from: {
      emailAddress: {
        address: "userB@example.com",
      }
    }
  },
  comment: `userB has something important to add.`
})
```

But get `ErrorSendAsDenied`.

How can I get permission for this? Is it even possible?

One alternative I have considered is forwarding the message to userB and then reply to that. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no other way. You will just have to forward the message first because *POST /users/UPN/messages/msg-id/reply* requires the message being replied and the sender to be associated with the one milbox.